# Is there any JPAv2-compatible vendor agnostic persistence api public available

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

The JPA 2 maven packages I've met so far was only complete realizations either from hibernate or eclipse. But I want to build my package agains vendor agnostic api. Is it available public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JPA spec group were too lazy to bother releasing a vendor neutral API jar for JPA 2.0 and JPA 2.1. See for example 
https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-60

You simply have to pick a vendor's own one and hope they didn't put vendor-specifics in there. Naff

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final`, `org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0` or `org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec:1.1`.

The Hibernate JAR has no implementation specific classes at all, the other two just contain some OSGi additions that won't do any harm when your application does not use OSGi.

While it would certainly be preferred to have an official `javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.x` artifact, I've never had any issues compiling against the Geronimo artifact with `provided` scope and using my compiled artifact with different persistence providers at runtime.