# How to use JPA in vendor neutral way?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, jpa-2.1

I've always been using vendor specific implementations of JPA. Now I'm looking for maven dependency for vendor neutral javax.persistence-api.persistence-api in the most recent version (2.1)

Seems I am only able to find version 1.0.2 from July 2007

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And more recent versions seem to be provided by vendors (hibernate-jpa-2.1-api, org.eclipse.persistence etc..)

What is the best method to use JPA 2.1 in the vendor neutral way? Which maven dependency do I need? I would expect version 2.1 as below, but can't find it, why?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586910/is-there-any-jpav2-compatible-vendor-agnostic-persistence-api-public-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no vendor neutral API artifact for **JPA 2.0 / 2.1**.

As you are devoloping a *Maven* project, you can pick up as a dependency one of the JPA provider vendor own artifact as the ones you guessed in your main thread.